# WPF Property not updated in UI when modified via derived class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, data-binding

I am unable to display the `CurrentStatus` property from my `ViewModelBase` class in the status bar of my WPF application.

`ViewModelBase` is inherited by `TasksViewModel` and `UserViewModel`.

`UserViewModel` is inherited by `ImportViewModel` and `TestViewModel`.

`MainWindow` has a DataContext of `TasksViewModel`.

**ViewModelBase:**

```
    public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _currentStatus;

        public string CurrentStatus
        {
            get { return _currentStatus; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _currentStatus)
                {
                    return;
                }
                _currentStatus = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentStatus));
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

**TasksViewModel:**

```
    public  class TasksViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public IEnumerable<ViewModelBase> Collection => _collection;
        public override string ViewModelName => "Tasks";
        public TasksViewModel()
        {
            _collection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>
                          {
                              new ImportUsersViewModel(),
                              new TestFunctionsViewModel()
                          };

            // Added as per John Gardner's answer below.
            // watch for currentstatus property changes in the internal view models and use those for our status
            foreach (ViewModelBase i in _collection)
            {
                i.PropertyChanged += InternalCollectionPropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        // Added as per John Gardner's answer.
        private void InternalCollectionPropertyChanged(object source, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = source as ViewModelBase;
            if (vm != null && e.PropertyName == nameof(CurrentStatus))
            {
                CurrentStatus = vm.CurrentStatus;
            }
        }
      }
```

**ImportUsersViewModel:**

```
internal class ImportUsersViewModel : UserViewModel
{
    private async void BrowseInputFileAsync()
    {
        App.Log.Debug("Browsing for input file.");
        string path = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(InputFile)
                          ? Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
                          : Path.GetDirectoryName(InputFile);
        InputFile = FileFunctions.GetFileLocation("Browse for User Import File",
                                                  path, FileFunctions.FileFilter.CSVTextAll) ?? InputFile;

        CurrentStatus = "Reading Import file.";
        ImportUsers = new ObservableCollection<UserP>();
        ImportUsers = new ObservableCollection<User>(await Task.Run(() => ReadImportFile()));
        string importResult =
            $"{ImportUsers.Count} users in file in {new TimeSpan(readImportStopwatch.ElapsedTicks).Humanize()}.";
        CurrentStatus = importResult; // Property is updated in ViewModelBase, but not in UI.
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ViewModel"
    xmlns:view="clr-namespace:Views"
    x:Class="MainWindow"
    Title="Users"
    Height="600"
    Width="1000"
    Icon="Resources/Icon.png">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ImportUsersViewModel}">
            <view:ImportUsers />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TestFunctionsViewModel}">
            <view:TestFunctionsView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:TasksViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <DockPanel>
        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="auto">
            <TextBlock Text="Status: " />
            <!-- Not updated in UI by any View Model -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentStatus}" />
        </StatusBar>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

If I bind a text block to the CurrentStatus property inside the `ImportUsers` UserControl it updates without issue, but the "parent" status bar does not update.

My suspicion is that it can't be displayed in the MainWindow status bar because, although both `ImportViewModel` and `TasksViewModel` inherit `ViewModelBase`, they don't have any link to each other, and the `TasksViewModel CurrentStatus` property isn't being updated.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Your post is hard to understand, way too much code. But something I catched is that you're updating an UI property (CurrentStatus) in an async function (BrowseInputFileAsync). I hope you're starting this function in the Dispatcher thread otherwise this won't update your UI and raise an exception on the CurrentStatus property.

Comment: I have pared down the code as suggested. CurrentStatus updates when bound inside the UserControl, but not in the MainWindow status bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your suspicion is correct.

The DataContext on the Window is a different ViewModel instance to that of the ImportUsersViewModel.

While CurrentStatus is defined in the same object hierarchy, the CurrentStatus line in the ImportUsersViewModel is changing a different object instance than the CurrentStatus property attached to the Window DataContext.

Answer (score 1):

Your window's `DataContext` is a `TaskViewModel`, but nothing on that view model is watching for property changes in it's collection, and updating itself.  essentially, TasksViewModel is *containing* the other viewmodels, but not aggregating any of their behaviors.

you need something like:

```
public  class TasksViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public IEnumerable<ViewModelBase> Collection => _collection;
    public override string ViewModelName => "Tasks";
    public TasksViewModel()
    {
        _collection = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>
                      {
                          new ImportUsersViewModel(),
                          new TestFunctionsViewModel()
                      };

        // watch for currentstatus property changes in the internal view models and use those for our status
        foreach (var i in _collection)
        {
             i.PropertyChanged += this.InternalCollectionPropertyChanged;
        }
    }
  }

  //
  // if a currentstatus property change occurred inside one of the nested
  // viewmodelbase objects, set our status to that status
  //
  private InternalCollectionPropertyChanged(object source, PropertyChangeEvent e)
  {
      var vm = source as ViewModelBase;
      if (vm != null && e.PropertyName = nameof(CurrentStatus))
      {
           this.CurrentStatus = vm.CurrentStatus;
      }
  }
```

Comment: `InternalCollectionPropertyChanged` does not seem to fire when the property is updated.

Comment: then we need to see your definition how you fire property change events in your base view model.  something like the above, while not exactly correct, should work.  use a debugger and step through.  if the internal one isn't getting hit (you did also add the lines in the constructor to hook it up?) then your property change notifications aren't working.

Comment: Added code for `OnPropertyChanged` event handler. Setting a breakpoint on `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentStatus));` shows that the property is being updated, and the UI shows the updated property in the UserControl, but not the status bar. I added the loop in the constructor, and placed another breakpoint on the `if` statement in the `InternalCollectionPropertyChanged`, which is not hit.